# PHP, Curl. Файл куки создается, но не наполняется

Tags: php, парсер, curl, cookie, данные

Есть код:

```
function sendCurl($url, $post = false, $referer = "") {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36");

    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept: */*', 'Connection: Keep-Alive', 'Origin: origin', 'Referer: '.$referer));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }
    $data = curl_exec ($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch))
        return curl_error($ch);
    if (curl_getinfo($ch)["http_code"] == 200)
        return $data;
}
```

При попытке отправить запрос на некоторые (не на все) сайты файл **cookie.txt** не наполняется данными. Почему так может быть? Что я делаю не так?

cookie.txt:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
```

**Суть задачи** - получить куки с сайта по аналогии с тем как их получает пользователь при переходе на сайт.

Comment: так может сайт и не отправляет никаких куки?

Comment: А еще соединение нужно закрывать

Comment: @AntonShchyrov пыха же сама закроет.

Comment: возможно потому куки в файл не записываются, потому что те некоторые сайты вовсе и не дают их тебе. Очень много лишних констант используешь, это неправильно.

Comment: Спасибо всем! Все верно, сервер не отдает куки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно потому куки в файл не записываются, потому что те некоторые сайты вовсе и не дают их тебе. Другая причина - у процесса не хватает прав на запись в файл.

Return в функции должен быть всегда, в твоем случае ретурны в двух условиях, но ведь они оба могут не выполниться, например, если вернется код 201 или 404.

Этот код работает:

```
function sendCurl($url, $post = false, $referer = "") {

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    if ($post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36'
        ]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    }

    if ($referer) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }

    //if (curl_getinfo($ch)["http_code"] == 200)
    return $response;
}


sendCurl('https://php.net/', false, 'http://google.ru');
//полученные куки
//# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
//# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
//# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.
//
//.php.net  TRUE    /   FALSE   1665218717  LAST_NEWS   1633682715
//.php.net  TRUE    /   FALSE   1634287517  COUNTRY NA%2C5.153.191.181


echo sendCurl('https://httpbin.org/post', true);
//получено
//{ "args": {}, "data": "1", "files": {}, "form": {}, "headers": { "Accept": "*/*", "Content-Length": "1", "Content-Type": "application/json", "Host": "httpbin.org", "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.61 Safari/537.36", "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-616005ef-60332e754318df001e64e069" }, "json": 1, "origin": "5.153.191.181", "url": "https://httpbin.org/post" }
```

Comment: Спасибо, все верно вы сказали!